# How to count class label frequency in a data frame using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this what is the easy method to count class label frequency of a particular class using the panda's data frame.

```
index  f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6  class_label
    0      4  4  2  3  3  1        0
    1      1  4  2  1  3  1        0
    2      4  1  2  1  3  1        0
    3      2  4  1  3  3  1        1
    4      4  4  2  0  3  1        1
    5      3  4  2  4  1  1        1
    6      4  4  2  5  3  1        1
    7      4  4  2  3  3  1        1
```

I have written down this code but is there any easy way to do this:

```
import pandas  as pd

df  = pd.read_csv('example.tsv',sep='\t')
class_labels  = df['class_label'].values.tolist()
class_labels_set = set(class_labels)

print class_labels

freq_list = []

for c in class_labels_set:
    freq_list.append(class_labels.count(c))

print 'Freq',freq_list
print 'number',class_labels_set
```

This code is very slow, on large files

Comment: `df['class_label'].value_counts()`?

Comment: I would guess that ayhan's answer is what you wanted.. but as an aside OP, in general with pandas if you find yourself turning a series into raw values or ever iterating over a series manually, then there's probably a better way to do whatever you're doing through the pandas API

Comment: @BrianJoseph I don't understand can you explain a little bit more? thank you.

Comment: @jax no problem! I'm guessing that you're fairly new to pandas. I was just letting you know that pandas has built-in functions for almost every use case that you can think of. And they tend to be really, really fast. So if you ever find your self typing `df['class_label'].values` or `for x in df['class_label']:...`, then you should stop and make sure you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [value_counts](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/series/series-value_counts.php). It's a useful way Pandas has to compute the frequency count.

As simple as `index.value_counts()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I had a similar problem. You want to know, how many lines you have in your dataset with the variable class_label==1 (or any number) - do I get this right?

If so, then I used similarly

```
df[df.class_label==x]
```

to give me a sub-array of only the lines, that meet this requirement and just

```
len(df[df.class_label==x])
```

to get the number of events, that meet the condition you specified.

Comment: a very easy solution is posted by @ayhan in the comment section which is df['class_label'].value_counts()

Comment: I saw the solution above, bit I thought, it would be okay to offer a different way to get the requested result. Therefore I don't understand the downvote, I just wanted to contribute an alternative, that I thought would be possibly helpful. For further analysis of the data, I felt that my way via that kind of sub-array might be also fine. If there are reasons, why the other solution is better, I would be glad to know it - I think, that would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't try your solution I will definitely give it a try. I didn't downvote your post but someone else. Thank for your answer.